# ArrayAdapter additions not showing in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a Android fragment containing a `ListView`, and I have attached an `ArrayAdapter` to the `ListView`, but when I insert items into the `ArrayAdapter`, the `ListView` only shows the first item.

`onCreateView` iterates over my Technologies, if they're unlocked, it adds them to the `ArrayList shownTechs`, but only the first item ever appears

```
public class TabTechnologyList extends Fragment {
  private static final String TAB_NAME = "tab_name";

  private ListView techList;
  private ArrayList<Technology> shownTechs = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayAdapter<Technology> techListAdapter;

  public TabTechnologyList() { }

  public static TabTechnologyList newInstance() {
    TabTechnologyList fragment = new TabTechnologyList();
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabData = Globals.getTabData();
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_technology_list, container, false);
    techList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabTechListList);

    techListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_techlist_element, shownTechs);
    techList.setAdapter(techListAdapter);
    for(Technology tech: tabData.getTechnologies()) {
        shownTechs.add(tech);
    }
    //Only the first one is shown on the screen
    return view;
  }
}
```

}

When I google for similar issues, people seem to be recreating the ArrayAdapter instead of editing the existing one, but I'm not doing that, and cant' figure out what problem remains.  Any suggestions?

fragment_technology_list.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.tbohne.kittens.front.TabTechnologyList"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabTechListList" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_techlist_element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>
```

**Addition**
I have just realized that this fragment is *not* filling the parent height, and is only tall enough to show the one entry, as if the fragment height were `wrap_content`.  (I can't scroll it, so it appears as if there's only the one).  This makes me think the nesting of fragments may be related, so here's the code that creates the fragment:

```
public class TabTechnology extends Fragment {
  private TabTechnologyList table;
  private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

  public TabTechnology() {}
  public static TabTechnology newInstance(String tabName) {[SNIP]}
  @Override public static onAttach(Activity activity) {[SNIP]}

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_technology, container, false);

    table = TabTechnologyList.newInstance(tabName);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.view_table, table);
    transaction.commit();

    return view;
  }
}
```

fragment_technology.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.tbohne.kittens.front.TabTechnology"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/view_table"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_details" />

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1px"
          android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/view_details"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling notifyDataSetChanged from UI thread. Is your OnItemUnlocked method running on UI thread?

Comment: Yes, everything is on the same thread.

Comment: what do you mean by *I am adding*

Comment: `shownTechs.add(tech);`?

Comment: Are all of 12 technologies unlocked initially? is shownTechs.add(tech) getting called 12 times inside onCreateView? Or is it only one is unlocked which is getting added and remaining 11 are geting unlockeListener set on them?

Comment: @Prashant: There were 12 that were unlocked and were added to the ArrayList.  I was later seeing them in the ListAdapter.  But not in the view.  I have edited the code to remove the "unlock" bits, since that seems to no longer be relevant.

Comment: Doesn't seems anything to be wrong with the code? Trying adding techListAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true) before setting adapter in ListView. And also call techListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() before returning view.

Comment: Is this everything that you have in your xml layout? Can you also share the xml layout of list view item?

Comment: I don't see the declaration of the field in the fragment. When you attach the debugger, can you confirm that `tabData` contains multiple items? What about `shownTechs`?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma: "The field"? which field?  When I attach to the debugger, `tabData` contains many items, which are also in `shownTechs`, `techListAdapter`, and I even see them in `techList.mAdapter.mAdapter.mObjects`if I wait until after things are on screen.

Comment: I was referring to the `tabData` field, which doesn't appear to be declared inside the TabTechnologyList fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the Fragment inside the `ScrollView` was the source of the problem.  Simply replaced those with `FrameLayout`, and suddenly everything magically works.  Very strange.
I suspect the problem has something to do with nesting scrollable objects.

Comment: Yes, indeed! This question is a perfect example of the XY Problem. The actual cause of this is that one of the ViewGroups is intercepting touch events: the ScrollView is handling them before the ListView gets a chance. It would be possible to combine the two, but you will need to extend your ScrollView and stop intercepting events in certain conditions. It's fairly unlikely that a user interface like this would make much sense, however, and I'd encourage you to rethink your approach.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma: Already done, replaced the ScrollView with a FrameLayout.